# In Oracle, how can I extract value of XML item in XML column?

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsql

I have XML column in Oracle table where i have this string:

**<field name="Text1" type="String"><value/>**

I need to extract the value of this field if exists, in the above example it doesn't exists.
In the below example the value exists:

**<field name="Text1" type="String"><value>12345</value>**

What will be the best way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As you said: **extract value**.

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '<field name="Text1" type="String"><value>12345</value></field>'
  3     from dual
  4    )
  5  SELECT extractvalue(xmltype(col), '/field/value') result
  6  from test;

RESULT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
12345

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`XMLTABLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/adxdb/xquery-and-XML-DB.html#GUID-4805CF1C-A00D-4B88-AF2E-00A9DB6F3392) would be a good choice to use in such a way that

```sql
SELECT x.*
  FROM xml_tab t,
       XMLTABLE('//Root'
                   PASSING xml_data
                    COLUMNS
                        field1      INT PATH 'field[@name="Text1"]/value',
                        field2      INT PATH 'field[@name="Text2"]/value'
                        ) x
```

returning

| FIELD1 | FIELD2 |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 |  |

where `xml_data` is

```
<Root>
  <field name="Text1" type="String">
    <value>12345</value>
  </field>
  <field name="Text2" type="String">
    <value/>
  </field>
</Root>
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a5c86e4d6dd574395954da5cacf9fe52)</kbd>

PS. *The `EXTRACTVALUE` function is deprecated. It is still supported for backward compatibility. However, Oracle recommends that you use the `XMLTABLE` function, or the `XMLCAST` and `XMLQUERY` functions instead*